# SQL query to extract employee details from access table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA. I have a user form in which I am trying to populate names of those employees who are AMO. I have a database called `Ofc`. Under which I have a table `EmployeeDetails`. Primary key is `PeoplesoftId`.

Here is the structure and the contents of the `Employee` table:

```
PeoplesoftId  Nameofemployee  RacifId  Employeeid  Designation
43243309      Maddala         V43309   99651823    AMO
43243310      Abhishek        A43301   99651824    AMO
43243311      Atanu           A43311   99651825    MO
43243312      Rajiv           R43312   99651826    CSE
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```vb
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim var
'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'Disable screen flickering.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
dbPath = "E:\office_hsbc\ofc.accdb"
var = "AMO"
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
cnn.Open
SQL = "SELECT Nameofemployee FROM EmployeeDetails where Designation= '" & var & "'"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
rs.Open SQL, cnn
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
Exit Sub
End If
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    comboamo.AddItem rs.Fields(i).Value, i
Next
rs.Close
cnn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Congratulation the data has been successfully Imported", vbInformation, "Import successful"
'error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Import_Data"
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move through each record in the recordset. Currently you are trying to read all of the fields from a single record but your query only returns one field. Try this instead:

```
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
Exit Sub
End If
i = 0
Do Until rs.EOF
    comboamo.AddItem rs.Fields("Nameofemployee").Value, i
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop
rs.Close
```